# Python Plotly chart update with two dropdowns

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, plotly-python

I am trying to build a plotly scatterplot in Jupyter Lab to be able to see dependencies between various columns in a DataFrame.
I want to have two dropdown menus (corresponding to the X and Y axes), in each of which a full list of the DF columns will be available. When I select a column in any of the menus, the data on the appropriate axis should be replaced by the column I selected (so, if I select the same column for X and Y, I would expect a straight line).

Below is my current implementation with a sample DataFrame:

```
# Creating the DataFrame    
temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (100, 10)))
col_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
temp.columns = col_list

# Init figure with the A column on both axes by default
fig = go.Figure()

default_col = 0
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=temp[col_list[default_col]].values,
        y=temp[col_list[default_col]].values,
        name="Metric correlation",
        mode="markers"
    ),
)
fig.update_xaxes(title_text=col_list[default_col])
fig.update_yaxes(title_text=col_list[default_col])

col_list = temp.columns

# Building options for each of the lists
btns_x = [
    dict(
        label=c,
        method="update",
        args=[
            {"x": temp[c].fillna(0).values,
             'xaxis': {'title': c}
             }],
    ) for c in col_list]


btns_y = [
    dict(
        label=c,
        method="update",
        args=[
            {"y": temp[c].fillna(0).values,
             'yaxis': {'title': c}
             }],
    ) for c in col_list]

# Adding the lists to the figure
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            buttons=btns_x,
            # method="update",
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="left",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
        dict(
            buttons=btns_y,
            # method="update",
            direction="down",
            pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
            showactive=True,
            x=0.1,
            xanchor="right",
            y=1.1,
            yanchor="top"
        ),
    ]
)
fig.update_layout(width=1000, height=1000)
fig.show()
```

The figure draws correctly initially:
[image]

Still, there are a few problems:

1. When I change values in a dropdown, it only works once. On the next tries nothing happens
2. If I first change the value on one dropdown and then on the other, all data disappears from the graph (see screenshot below)
3. The axes labels are not being updated
   [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just about being systematic around the list comprehensions. Below fully works,  allows selection of any column and updates appropriate axis title.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

temp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, (100, 10)))
col_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]
temp.columns = col_list

fig = px.scatter(temp, x="A", y="B")

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {axis: [temp[c]]},
                        {f"{axis}axis": {"title": {"text": c}}},
                    ],
                }
                for c in temp.columns
            ],
            "x": 0 if axis == "x" else 0.1,
            "y": 1.2,
        }
        for axis in "xy"
    ]
)
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to work perfectly and is quite elegant :) I will accept this, but will be grateful if you can tell me where I went wrong in my initial answer - seems like I did more or less the same stuff but repeated manually the button generation over the x/y axis

Comment: I believe the issue is here `{"x": temp[c].fillna(0).values,
             'xaxis': {'title': c}
             }` should be `{"x": [temp[c].fillna(0).values]},
             {'xaxis': {'title': c}}
             }` IMHO a bit of a quirk where values needs to be a 2D list and data and layout need to be separate dicts